# Displaying File level metrics in SonarQube

Tags: java, sonarqube, dashboard, metrics

I Am new to SonarQube and I am developing a plugin that displays the file level metrics in the web page.

I am able to access the file level metrics in the decorate method and I need the same in my web page(in dashboard).

But when I display in my dashboard only the Project level metrics gets displayed.

How to get File level metrics in the dashboard.

Am accessing the File level metrics as below:

```
public void decorate(Resource resource, DecoratorContext context) {
if(Qualifiers.isFile(resource)){
Measure m=context.getMeasure(CoreMetrics.NCLOC);
LOG.info("Decorator File NCLOC: "+m.getValue()); //Prints the number of lines in the current file.
}
}
```

Am using SonarQube Runner to analyze the file and in my command prompt the value gets displayed. I need the same to be displayed in the Widget.

I am sure where to edit the widget class. Is it in the .html.erb file or java file and how?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Widgets are only displayed on dashboards, and dashboard are only displayed at project or module levels.

If you want to be able to see you metric at file level, you can install the [Tab Metrics plugin](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Tab+Metrics+Plugin).

Comment: Hi Fabrice, thanks for your reply. I need to display it in a different perspective. I have posted it here. can u please help with this. I need to store the metrics in a different way. http://sonarqube.15.x6.nabble.com/sonar-dev-changing-the-way-sonar-stores-the-metrics-td5030489.html